# return bool value from middleware to express controller

Tags: angularjs, express

I want to return a boolean value from middleware defined as

```
module.exports = {
   authenticatepracticename: function(pname) {  
       ecollection.find({ $and: [{'name':pname},{'status' : 'active'}] }).exec(function (err, result) {
           if (err) return false;
           if(result.length == 1){
               // console.log('true');
               return true;
            }
            else{
                // console.log('false');
                return false;
            }
       });  
   },
   // ... 
}
```

to my express controller defined as

```
exports.checkcredentails = function (req, res) {  
    var result = practice.authenticatepracticename(practiceName);
}
```

but result is coming `undefined` even though middleware function is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting `undefined` result from `practice.authenticatepracticename` is because `ecollection.find` performs asynchronous action and `authenticatepracticename` end without returning any value (which is `undefined` in JavaScript).

In order to improve that, you would need to provide a callback function from your `checkcredentails` to `authenticatepracticename`.

**Example:**

```
exports.checkcredentails = function (req, res) {  
    practice.authenticatepracticename(practiceName, function(err, result){
        // you can handle error and result here e.g. by sending them back to a customer
        res.send("Result: " + result);
    });
}
```

And your `authenticatepracticename`:

```
authenticatepracticename: function(pname, cb) {
    ecollection.find({ $and: [{'name':pname},{'status' : 'active'}] }).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) return cb(err)
        if(result.length == 1){
            // console.log('true');
            cb(null, true)
        }
        else {
            // console.log('false');
            cb(null, false)
        }
    });  
}
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: Make sure to return after `cb(err)` (or use `return cb(err)`), otherwise the callback may get called twice.